# The itemListOrder property of an itemList element of a json+ld markup for a Top Products list should be ascending or descending?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

**From:** https://schema.org/ItemList

[image]

If that list will be displayed to the users as:

```
1. HP Pavilion
2. Dell XPS 15
3. Lenovo ThinkPad
```

Should the `itemListOrder` property be `Ascending` or `Descending`?

I would think that it should be `Ascending`, but their example got me confused.